# Is there something like head(), summary() of R in python?

Tags: python, summary

R has several convenient functions like head(), summary() to show the content of an object concisely. What are the ways to show the content of python data object concisely? Thanks.

Comment: `myObject.__dict__` will give you a dict representation of the object's fields and their values, if that's what you're after. It depends entirely on what you mean be "concisely" and what object you're talking about.

Comment: Well-written objects will implement `__repr__` in a nice way as to provide the caller with good information when they call `repr(o)`.

Comment: Pandas has a [describe function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#summarizing-data-describe), similar to summary() in R

Comment: @erocoar Does `numpy` has something to pandas' `describe()` function?

Comment: [this](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.describe.html) might be what you're looking for